# Get average from column gruped by date

Tags: sql

I have problem with query. I have data like this:

| value | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 22.12 | 2023-01-18T08:00:35.000Z |
| 22.18 | 2023-01-18T09:13:12.000Z |
| 22.15 | 2023-01-18T09:16:12.000Z |
| 22.17 | 2023-01-18T09:49:35.000Z |
| 16.12 | 2023-01-25T10:15:05.000Z |
| 26.18 | 2023-01-25T10:40:05.000Z |
| 25.52 | 2023-01-25T10:55:05.000Z |
| 19.88 | 2023-01-26T11:40:05.000Z |
| 16.12 | 2023-01-16T12:40:05.000Z |

Is it possible to write query where I can get average of values gruped by date?
For example:

```
2023-01-18 - average: 22
2023-01-25 - average: 19
```

Comment: Could you please tag your DBMS? And why should the average be 19 for 2023-01-25? The average for this date will be 22.61 according to your sample data. For none of your days, the average would be 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert timestamp to a date value and use it in `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select cast(timestamp as date) as dt, AVG(value) as avg_val
from tbl_name
group by cast(timestamp as date);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works great. I have one more question. Is it possible to display only date without a time after the average has been grouped?